# I want to use hashmap in a java class which produces XML format, but I am getting JAXB exceptions

Tags: java, xml, angularjs

This is my java class where I have to use hash map for getting key-value:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Combo {

    private Map<Combo, List<Combo>> businessDomainAndBusinessSubDomainsPair = new HashMap<Combo, List<Combo>>();

    public Map<Combo, List<Combo>> getBusinessDomainAndBusinessSubDomainsPair() {
        return businessDomainAndBusinessSubDomainsPair;
    }
    public void setBusinessDomainAndBusinessSubDomainsPair(
            Map<Combo, List<Combo>> businessDomainAndBusinessSubDomainsPair) {
        this.businessDomainAndBusinessSubDomainsPair = businessDomainAndBusinessSubDomainsPair;
    }
}
```

But in angular code I am getting this error on debug:
[image]

I tried using LinkedHashMap also but still I am getting error. Can any one please suggest a solution for this.

Comment: Did you tried these : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795793/jaxb-illegalannotationexceptions and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937472/jaxb-illegalannotationexceptions ?

Comment: Is it just in the debugger that you have problems or does that normal code throw exceptions too?

Comment: code throws Unexpected Token but i didn't get the values in html page

Comment: can you add stacktrace to question?